# Looking for a solution to run agenda based cron jobs to executed in only in one pod of kubernetes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, kubernetes, cron

I am having difficulty figuring out how to run cron jobs in single pod and not in all of them. I also have a mongodb db-trigger that listens for any changes in db and based on that notifications are send to users, which is also getting executed multiple times.

I came across below solutions that does not fit my requirements,

1. Use Queue with help of Redis or RabbitMQ
2. Create a separate microservice and run those jobs in single pod

Thank You in advance

Comment: You can try KEDA ScaledJobs in combination with Queue/Database Triggers

Comment: Why avoid the approaches you listed?  The other obvious approach is using a Kubernetes CronJob to launch tasks, but again, this will run in a separate pod.

Comment: @DavidMaze

Both approach will require me to rewrite code and create a separate code base to share common services used by both platform.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using bee-queue node package to push all jobs in redis and process it.